# How to get cam(0) in the NanoPC T4 with its MIPI Camera?

Tags: ubuntu, arm, opencv3.0

I am testing on the NanoPC T4 with its 13Mp onboard camera Camera OV13850.

I can open and test through provided test scripts.

Is there any way to use this camera from OepnCV like :

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
```

Comment: same problem here. Where this NanoPc . Guys?